# EmailComposer Cordova Plugin

Tags: iphone, xcode, cordova

I have tried to add the EmailComposer plugin for Cordova that can be found [here](https://github.com/Molitov/Cordova-EmailComposer)

I have followed it step by step, when I come to build the project I get the following error -

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_MFMailComposeViewController", referenced from:

I have made sure that I have added the MessageUI.framework to the project. It is currently in the framework folder.

Can someone point me in the right direction or know what else I need to provide in order to further trouble shoot this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was simply a case of not adding the framework correctly to the project, I removed and did it again correctly